# Pixel art creator: loading saved pixel data from Room causes strange Canvas bug/glitch

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

I'm creating a pixel art editor application using Canvas, and the pixel art data is saved into a Room database.

Here's the canvas code:

```
package com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.customviews

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.*
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.converters.JsonConverter
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.database.AppData
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.listeners.CanvasFragmentListener
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.models.Pixel
import kotlin.math.sqrt

class MyCanvasView(context: Context, val spanCount: Double) : View(context) {
    lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
    lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap

    val rectangles = mutableMapOf<RectF, Paint?>()

    private lateinit var caller: CanvasFragmentListener

    private var thisWidth: Int = 0
    private var scale: Double = 0.0

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        thisWidth = w

        caller = context as CanvasFragmentListener

        if (::extraBitmap.isInitialized) extraBitmap.recycle()

        extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(extraBitmap)

        scale = (w / spanCount)

        for (i in 0 until spanCount.toInt()) {
            for (i_2 in 0 until spanCount.toInt()) {
                val rect = RectF((i * scale).toFloat(), (i_2 * scale).toFloat(), (i * scale).toFloat() + scale.toFloat(), (i_2 * scale).toFloat() + scale.toFloat())

                rectangles[rect] = null
                extraCanvas.drawRect(rect, Paint().apply { style = Paint.Style.FILL; color = Color.WHITE })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun drawRectAt(x: Float, y: Float) {
        for (rect in rectangles.keys) {
            if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                caller.onPixelTapped(this, rect)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> drawRectAt(event.x, event.y)
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> drawRectAt(event.x, event.y)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
    }

    fun saveData(): List<Pixel> {
        val data = mutableListOf<Pixel>()

        for (pair in rectangles) {
            data.add(Pixel(pair.value?.color))
        }

        return data
    }

    fun loadData(context: LifecycleOwner, index: Int) {
        AppData.db.pixelArtCreationsDao().getAllPixelArtCreations().observe(context, {
            currentPixelArtObj = it[index]
            val localPixelData = JsonConverter.convertJsonStringToPixelList(currentPixelArtObj.pixelData)

            var index = 0

            for (i in 0 until sqrt(localPixelData.size.toDouble()).toInt()) {
                for (i_2 in 0 until sqrt(localPixelData.size.toDouble()).toInt()) {
                    val rect = RectF((i * scale).toFloat(), (i_2 * scale).toFloat(), (i * scale).toFloat() + scale.toFloat(), (i_2 * scale).toFloat() + scale.toFloat())

                    rectangles[rect] = null

                    extraCanvas.drawRect(rect, Paint().apply { style = Paint.Style.FILL; isAntiAlias = false; color = localPixelData[index].pixelColor ?: Color.WHITE })

                    rectangles[rectangles.keys.toList()[index]] = Paint().apply { style = Paint.Style.FILL; isAntiAlias = false; color = localPixelData[index].pixelColor ?: Color.WHITE }

                    index++
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how a 10 by 10 canvas may look like:

[image]

The pixel data is saved into a Room database as a Json String, and whenever we want to access this data we convert the Json String back to a `List<Pixel>`, et cetera:

**Dao:**

```
@Dao
interface PixelArtCreationsDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertPixelArt(pixelArt: PixelArt)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM PixelArt ")
    fun getAllPixelArtCreations(): LiveData<List<PixelArt>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM PixelArt WHERE objId=:pixelArtId")
    fun deletePixelArtCreation(pixelArtId: Int)

    @Query("UPDATE PixelArt SET item_bitmap=:bitmap WHERE objId=:id_t")
    fun updatePixelArtCreationBitmap(bitmap: String, id_t: Int): Int

    @Query("UPDATE PixelArt SET item_pixel_data=:pixelData WHERE objId=:id_t")
    fun updatePixelArtCreationPixelData(pixelData: String, id_t: Int): Int

    @Query("UPDATE PixelArt SET item_favourited=:favorited WHERE objId=:id_t")
    fun updatePixelArtCreationFavorited(favorited: Boolean, id_t: Int): Int
}
```

**PixelArt database:**

```
@Database(entities = [PixelArt::class], version = 1)
abstract class PixelArtDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun pixelArtCreationsDao(): PixelArtCreationsDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: PixelArtDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): PixelArtDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(PixelArtDatabase::class) {
                    if (instance == null) instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, PixelArtDatabase::class.java, AppData.dbFileName).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

**AppData:**

```
class AppData {
    companion object {
        var dbFileName = "pixel_art_db"
        lateinit var db: PixelArtDatabase
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity
data class PixelArt(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_bitmap") var bitmap: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_title") var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_pixel_data") var pixelData: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_favourited") var favourited: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_date_created") var dateCreated: String = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now())) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var objId = 0
}
```

Now, say we have two projects like so with two different `spanCount` values:

[image]

Once we click on the first item, the following occurs:

[image]

For some reason it's setting the grid size to be equal to that of the second item, and I'm really trying to understand why this is the case. I've tried to fix this weird glitch and have had no luck doing so.

But, for some reason when we go to our second item it renders properly:

[image]

If we create a *new* 80 x 80 canvas and then go back to the *second* creation it will render like so:

[image]

I'm assuming that it's setting the `spanCount` to that of the latest item in the database, but I'm unsure why this is happening.

I suspect it has something to do with the code that takes the `List<Pixel>` and draws it onscreen:

```
fun loadData(context: LifecycleOwner, index: Int) {
        AppData.db.pixelArtCreationsDao().getAllPixelArtCreations().observe(context, {
            currentPixelArtObj = it[index]
            val localPixelData = JsonConverter.convertJsonStringToPixelList(currentPixelArtObj.pixelData)

            var index = 0

            for (i in 0 until sqrt(localPixelData.size.toDouble()).toInt()) {
                for (i_2 in 0 until sqrt(localPixelData.size.toDouble()).toInt()) {
                    val rect = RectF((i * scale).toFloat(), (i_2 * scale).toFloat(), (i * scale).toFloat() + scale.toFloat(), (i_2 * scale).toFloat() + scale.toFloat())

                    rectangles[rect] = null

                    extraCanvas.drawRect(rect, Paint().apply { style = Paint.Style.FILL; isAntiAlias = false; color = localPixelData[index].pixelColor ?: Color.WHITE })

                    rectangles[rectangles.keys.toList()[index]] = Paint().apply { style = Paint.Style.FILL; isAntiAlias = false; color = localPixelData[index].pixelColor ?: Color.WHITE }

                    index++
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Although I'm not entirely sure where the source of the bug is coming from, because it seems I'm doing everything right. What can I try next?

Comment: Is the canvas view permanently displayed, and you're telling it to show different images by calling ``loadData`` on it? You're initialising your ``scale`` property in ``onSizeChanged``, which only happens when the view is laid out (and I'm not sure what ``spanCount`` is in that method, but it looks sus too). You definitely need to recalculate that stuff whenever you load a new pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed by calling `invalidate()` on the Fragment's Canvas property after the user taps the back button. It took me a couple of days to get to fix this, so I'm posting an answer here in case someone has a similar bug.

```
fun CanvasActivity.extendedOnBackPressed() {
    canvasFragmentInstance.myCanvasViewInstance.invalidate()

    startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
}
```